# Defining a global variable in Cypress that can be used in all test files without creating a new one every time

Tags: cypress

I am looking for a solution to define a global variable and access it in all my test files. This is my `commands.js`. Here I am generating a random mobile number using faker.js. I am doing API automated testing but the APIs are executed in a sequence which means there should be one mobile number and one user ID that should be used throughout the test execution.

```javascript
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';
Cypress.Commands.add('generateAndSetMobileNumber', () => {
  // Check if the mobile number is already set in the Cypress environment
  if (!Cypress.env('mobileNumber')) {
    const mobileNumber = faker.datatype.number({ min: 5700000000, max: 5899999999 });
    Cypress.env('mobileNumber', mobileNumber.toString());
  }
});

Cypress.Commands.add('createUser', () => {
  cy.generateRandomMobileNumber().then((mobileNumber) => {

    return cy.api({
      failOnStatusCode: false,
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/products/users/',
      body: {
        "countryCode": "971",
        "mobileNo": mobileNumber,
        "viewId": "createView",
        "agentCode": "",
        "language": "EN",
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      expect(response.status).to.eq(201);
      Cypress.env('prospectId', response.body.userId);
    });
  });
});
```

Now these commands are defined here and are working perfectly fine but when I use it in my test classes everything generates a new mobile number and new userID whereas I want one UserID and mobileNumber that can be used throughout the execution.

This is my test file:

```javascript
describe("Generating OTP", () => {
before(() => {
 cy.createUser() => {
     
    });
  it("Verify user is able to generate OTP by entering their mobile number", () => {
               UserId = Cypress.env('UserId');
               mobileNumber = Cypress.env('mobileNumber');


    cy.api({
      failOnStatusCode: false,
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'products/otp',
      body: {
        "action": "generate",
        "prospectId": prospectId,
        "countryCode": "971",
        "mobileNo": mobileNumber,
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      // Assert that the OTP was generated successfully
      expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
      expect(prospectId).to.have.length(5);
      // Assert that the OTP is valid
      expect(response.body.verified).to.eq(true);
    });
  });
});
```

I have tried multiple options as follow, but nothing seems to be working for me:

1. `cypress-localstorage-commands` plugin
2. `setLocalStorage`
3. `getAllSessionStorage`
4. `cy.wrap`

Comment: If you want it generated once and only once why not create it in the Cypress [config file](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration)?

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe how can i define it in config file, please can you elaborated as the userID is generated in an API response.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a global variable, which is highly difficult to reason about in a larger codebase, you probably would like to take a look at the [Singleton design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton).

```
var PhoneNumber = (function () {
    var instance;

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = (create phone number here);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();
```

Then you can use is like this:

```
var phoneNumber = PhoneNumber.getInstance()
```

If you use Typescript, you can use this:

```
class PhoneNumber {
    private static instance: PhoneNumber;

    private constructor() { }

    
    public static getInstance(): PhoneNumber {
        if (!PhoneNumber.instance) {
            PhoneNumber.instance = (create phone number here);
        }

        return PhoneNumber.instance;
    }
}
```

This way, there is no chance of some other code interfering with the phone number.

Comment: Hi @Joao,
Please can you be more specific as this does not answers my question

Comment: @MariamAslam The Singleton pattern is a way to tackle your problem of having a shared state in the context of your execution. Global variable is also a way, but it's known to be more complicated to deal with. Maybe I missed the root of your question and you don't want to have this shared state - if that's the case, let me know what I missed.